# get the end or the period of execution of a running process NSIS

Tags: architecture, cmd, system, exe, nsis

How to get the time to know if my running process is end ?
i'll launch first.exe that push a second.exe and return the time process ending of second.exe for my first.exe

Answer (score 0):

`ExecWait '"c:\path\to\app.exe" /foo "bar baz" --bye' $0` will wait for app.exe and gives you the exit code it `$0`

Comment: File /oname=$PLUGINSDIR\hatier.jpg "image.jpg"
newadvsplash::show /NOUNLOAD $12 3000 1000 -1 /BANNER /NOCANCEL $PLUGINSDIR\image.jpg
Pop $0
sleep 1000
Delete $PLUGINSDIR\image.jpg   Exec "LauncherDesktop.exe"
ExecWait '"LauncherDesktop.exe" /foo "bar baz" --bye' $12

;ExecWait "MN_DIDIER.exe"
Sleep $12

Comment: My first.exe I write this: I make a splash in the background and a app2.exe I want the splash ends one second after launch app2.exe becaufe after the first launch it takes 30 second and 5 seconds the second launch and splash like that have 25 seconds more, waste of time. 

File / oname = $ PLUGINSDIR \ image.jpg "image.jpg" 
newadvsplash :: show / NOUNLOAD $ 12 3000 1000 -1 / BANNER / $ NOCANCEL PLUGINSDIR \ image.jpg 
Pop $ 0 
sleep 1000 
Delete $ PLUGINSDIR \ image.jpg 
Exec "app2.exe" 
ExecWait "app2.exe" / foo "bar baz" - bye '$ 12 

Sleep $ 12 @Anders

Comment: Edit your question if you want to add more code, I cannot read that mess you posted here...